# Always ask for authentication when using popup window on IE6

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem with pop up window on IE6. It always redirect to login page. It's ok for for Firefox or IE8.

In Web.config, I configured all files are required to login:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="frmLogin" loginUrl="/Default.aspx" defaultUrl="/Home"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

When user input correct username and password, I use the following to provide authentication

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
```

By using the above code, user could view all pages.

But in IE6 & 7:

- It's ok if user view page with the same window
- But if i open it pop up window using javascript as below, it asks for authentication again:

  window.open(url, null, "width=1050, height=600, scrollbars=yes");

Thanks!

Comment: This is not enough code, post relevant code and state your question clearly. Your welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this authentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true);
```